Airflow 2.10.3 how to extract information about task instances?
I use Airflow 2.10.3 and I'd like to retrieve informations about when a task starts, ends, its status (e.g. success, fail) and similar attributes.
I found a PostgreSQL database with all the list of app, dag and similar, in a schema called scheduler, but there's no information about what I'm looking for.
I'd like to know if there is a way I can do a query (e.g. with DBeaver or Qlik) to extract what I see in the Airlow console, in pages like:

DAG runs;
Jobs;
Audit Logs;
Task Instances;
SLA Misses.


You could set, from here postgresql.conf, log_statement= all. Then go through the pages in the console and see what queries show up in the log. FYI,  log_statement= all will generate a lot of logs so it should be a temporary setting change.

There's an ERD for the database here https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/database-erd-ref.html but note it is recommended that you use the REST API rather than access the dbms directly. (Probably to avoid possible performance of locking issues.)
